# Comparing heating soldering with high current cold heat soldering

Tags: soldering, safety

which is more harmful to electronic components, mainly semiconductor ones, heat of heating solder iron or substantially high current of cold heat soldering (basically just miniature arc welding)

Comment: Heat in general because if Cold Heat is doing what it is supposed to be doing, the high current of cold heat soldering shouldn't be flowing anywhere but in and out of the single pin. The issues with the Cold Heat are more nuanced: If you touch more than a single pin, bad things will happen. Difficult to temperature control. Difficult to directly heat up both pad and component simultaneously from the tip. The tip material itself.

Comment: in professional assembly cold heat is simply forbidden. There are also chemical issues and flux distribution that can only be achieved with 'uniform' heating of the solder joints. Components are simply designed to handle the heat of a well done solder operation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [cold heat website](https://www.coldheat.com/):

> We do not recommend the ColdHeat Cordless Soldering Pen for soldering temperature-sensitive or very small electronic components, because the temperature variation of the tip can be dramatic and quick, too quick even for your incredible reflexes. Similarly, it will not work handsomely on large joints that require long, continuous soldering, because it is more of a small-devil sort of creature.